# Reproducing Graphics Object Cannot be Created from Indexed Pixel Format

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+

I'm trying to reproduce 'https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/solution-for-a-graphics-object-cannot-be-created-from-an-im/'

I'm trying to create and save a Bitmap with Pixel Format set to `Dont care` ,but i keep getting `Parameter not valid` exception.

```
            Bitmap orig = new Bitmap(500,500);
            Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(orig.Width, orig.Height,
                System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);

            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(clone))
            {
                gr.DrawImage(orig, new Rectangle(0, 0, clone.Width, clone.Height));
            }
            clone.Save("test.png");
```

Comment: Both of your images are new. Where is the original? The `orig` here is not a `xbppIndexed` format.

Comment: [BITMAPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfo) => [BITMAPINFOHEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfoheader)`->biBitCount = 0`,  `->biCompression = BI_PNG`, `CreateDIBSection()` (`DIB_RGB_COLORS`) + (`CreateCompatibleDC()` + `SelectObject()`) x 2, => `BitBlt(hdc_dest, 0, 0, width, height, hdc_screen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY)`.

Comment: @JQSOFT How can i convert a an image to indexed pixel format.. for reproducing this error. Is it possible using IrfanView?

Comment: @Jimi Thanks.. Please see the comment above.

Comment: You can create an Indexed Bitmap. You cannot derive a Graphics object from it. E.g. `using (Bitmap indexed = new Bitmap(100, 100, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)) { indexed.Save("somewhere.png"); };`. You cannot create one with `PixelFormat.DontCare`. That `PixelFormat` is set when the Bitmap is set to null, already disposed or otherwise invalid.

Comment: Sorry I was offline. Jimi did answer that one. Also you can try the `PixelFormat4bppIndexed` and 'PixelFormat8bppIndexed'. Good luck.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks but i meant .. how can i convert an existing image to Index Pixel format ? When i do it ,the complete image becomes black.

Comment: You'ld have to generate the [Palette](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.palette) yourself, applying a color quantization algo to the Bitmap data (using `Bitmap.LockBits` to analyze the image). Look for `Octree-based Quantization`. Or save the image as GIF and get the (horrific) palette that the encoder generates (base dithering algorithm). Or you could use the [FormatConvertedBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.formatconvertedbitmap) Class  (System.Windows.Media).

Comment: @Jimi Can use some tool like photoshop/irfan view to generate/convert an indexed pixel format image?

Comment: These can also be interesting: [How to: Use a Color Remap Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-a-color-remap-table) (but see the whole MSDN Document structure on the left) -- [Implementing K-Means Image Segmentation Algorithm](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1203227/Implementing-K-Means-Image-Segmentation-Algorithm) -- [ImageMagick v6 Examples: Color Quantization and Dithering](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/).

Comment: Sure, you can use an Image editor to generate an indexed Bitmap. In PhotoShop: `Image -> Mode -> Indexed`. It will generate an Indexed Bitmap of a specified Color palette. You can then save the Image as PNG and use a PictureBox to show it. But you, still, cannot generate a Graphics object from it (using the System.Drawing implementation). You'll have to convert it.

Comment: @Jimi I have tried doing that in Photoshop and saving it as PNG,but the error cannot be reproduced in C# .. Please see https://imgur.com/a/q8NL6YK

Comment: What does it mean *the error cannot be reproduced*? You don't get an exception when you try to `var indexedImage = new Bitmap("The Indexed Bitmap Path", true) var g = Graphics.FromImage(indexedImage);`? Have you inspected the `indexedImage.PixelFormat`? It should read `Format8bppIndexed`. -- Load a new Image in PhotoShop. When you select `Image → Mode`, you should see `Indexed Color...`. A dialog opens. Set `Palette = Local, Colors = 256, Forced = Primaries Matte = none, Dither = none`. Save the Image as PNG (Jpeg should not be available), ticking the ICC Profile option. Use Compression = none

Comment: @Jimi Yes.I'm referring to the exception in C#.I followed your steps and saved the image as PNg .. but still the exception cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @JQSOFT Thanks .... Please post the link in the comments... Could you please send me an image with indexed pixel format for testing?

Comment: @JQSOFT Thanks.....